# Unity2D right letterbox issue

Tags: android, unity-game-engine, mobile

I am working on a 2D game in Unity2018

when my game is running in different ratio a letterbox is automatically added

[image: Issue PNG]

how to render game with full screen mode in every screen ratio ?

Comment: stretch, tile, 9-slice.. many choices.

Comment: thank for your help, i will check it